Vue js sorting table
I'm getting one issue some strange, I have one table and I added the sort function, this is my code:
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { ref, computed, watch } from 'vue'

  const data = ref([
    {
      header: {
        id_file: '11',
        id_client: '0',
        client_txid: '01TF 49608',
        spa_status: 'A',
      },
      try_log: [
        {
          hac_id: '184',
          exec_date: '2024-08-05T20:32:25.579Z',
          api_env: 'PRODUCCION_REAL',
        },
        {
          hac_id: '168',
          exec_date: '2024-08-05T18:54:57.535Z',
          api_env: 'PRODUCCION_REAL',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      header: {
        id_file: '11',
        id_client: '0',
        client_txid: '01MN 177338',
        spa_status: 'TIMEOUT',
      },
      try_log: [
        {
          hac_id: '184',
          exec_date: '2024-08-05T20:32:25.579Z',
          api_env: 'PRODUCCION_REAL',
        },
        {
          hac_id: '168',
          exec_date: '2024-08-05T18:54:57.535Z',
          api_env: 'PRODUCCION_REAL',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      header: {
        id_file: '11',
        id_client: '0',
        client_txid: '01MN 177338',
        spa_status: 'PAGADA',
      },
      try_log: [
        {
          hac_id: '167',
          exec_date: '2024-08-05T18:54:55.780Z',
          api_env: 'PRODUCCION_REAL',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      header: {
        id_file: '500',
        id_client: '850',
        client_txid: 'TRX-VE4586-T3',
        spa_status: '',
      },
      try_log: [
        {
          hac_id: '166',
          exec_date: '2024-08-05T18:54:51.719Z',
          api_env: 'PRODUCCION_REAL',
        },
      ],
    },
  ])

  const page = ref(1)
  const itemsPerPage = ref(10)
  const sortBy = ref<string>('')
  const sortDirection = ref<string>('asc')
  const filteredData = ref(data.value)

  const filters = ref({
    search: '',
    id_file: '',
  })

  const normalizeValue = (value: any) => {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      return value.toLowerCase()
    }
    if (typeof value === 'number' || typeof value === 'boolean') {
      return value.toString()
    }
    return value
  }

  function sortTable(column: string) {

    if (sortBy.value === column) {
      sortDirection.value = sortDirection.value === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'
    } else {
      sortBy.value = column
      sortDirection.value = 'asc'
    }

    const modifier = sortDirection.value === 'asc' ? 1 : -1

    const sortedData = [...filteredData.value].sort((a, b) => {
      const aValue = normalizeValue(a.header[column] ?? ''); 
      const bValue = normalizeValue(b.header[column] ?? '');

      if (!aValue && !bValue) return 0; // Both null, no change in order
      if (!aValue) return 1; // a is null, move b before a (descending)
      if (!bValue) return -1; // b is null, move a before b (ascending)

      // Existing comparison logic
      if (aValue < bValue) return -1 * modifier;
      if (aValue > bValue) return 1 * modifier;

      return 0
    })

    filteredData.value = sortedData
  }

  watch(
    filters,
    () => {
      page.value = 1
      filteredData.value = data.value.filter((item) => {
        return Object.values(item.header).some((value) =>
          String(value).toLowerCase().includes(filters.value.search.toLowerCase())
        )
      })
    },
    { immediate: true }
  )

  const paginatedData = computed(() => {
    if (itemsPerPage.value === 0) return filteredData.value
    const start = (page.value - 1) * itemsPerPage.value
    const end = start + itemsPerPage.value
    return filteredData.value.slice(start, end)
  })


  watch(filters, () => {
    page.value = 1
  })

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div class="list-view-toolbar">
      <div class="search-field">
        <VField>
          <VControl
            icon="feather:search"
            style="margin: 0"
          >
            <input
              v-model="filters.search"
              class="input custom-text-filter"
              placeholder="Search..."
            >
          </VControl>
        </VField>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="datatable-wrapper">
    <div
      class="table-container"
      style="overflow: auto"
    >
      <table class="table datatable-table is-fullwidth">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th
              class="col-estatus"
              align="center"
              @click="sortTable('id_client')"
            >
              id_client
              <span v-if="sortBy === 'id_client'">
                <i
                  v-if="sortDirection === 'asc'"
                  class="iconify"
                  data-icon="feather:chevron-up"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                />
                <i
                  v-else
                  class="iconify"
                  data-icon="feather:chevron-down"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                />
              </span>
            </th>
            <th
              class="col-estatus"
              align="center"
              @click="sortTable('client_txid')"
            >
              client_txid
              <span v-if="sortBy === 'client_txid'">
                <i
                  v-if="sortDirection === 'asc'"
                  class="iconify"
                  data-icon="feather:chevron-up"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                />
                <i
                  v-else
                  class="iconify"
                  data-icon="feather:chevron-down"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                />
              </span>
            </th>
            <th
              class="col-estatus"
              align="center"
              @click="sortTable('id_file')"
            >
              id_file
              <span v-if="sortBy === 'id_file'">
                <i
                  v-if="sortDirection === 'asc'"
                  class="iconify"
                  data-icon="feather:chevron-up"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                />
                <i
                  v-else
                  class="iconify"
                  data-icon="feather:chevron-down"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                />
              </span>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr
            v-for="(item, index) in paginatedData"
            :key="index"
          >
            <td
              class="col-id-cliente"
              align="center"
            >
              {{ item.header.id_client }}
            </td>
            <td
              class="col-id-beneficiario"
              align="center"
            >
              {{ item.header.client_txid }}
            </td>
            <td
              class="col-id-cliente"
              align="center"
            >
              {{ item.header.id_file }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


so, the function sortTable is for sort datatable asc or desc if I click on header client_txid datatable sorted in ascending order but If I click again on header client_txid I got this issue on console:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore')

why I'm getting this issue???
and how I can fix it?

It is not reproducible when pasted in https://play.vuejs.org.  Only difference is in the playground VControl and VField are not defined (not sure where they come from), but try deleting them in your actual code and testing if the error still exists. If not, the error could be traced back to them. Otherwise, perhaps it is related to specific project environment.  What exact versions of Vue, Vite, etc?  Include package.json in the question.

I pasted the code on play.vuejs.org and worked!!! I ignore tags VField and VControl and another one VFlexPagination........ so I remove the tags VField, VControl and  VFlexPagination in my code, and I tested the sort and I got the same error,..... I'm working on vue 3.3.4, vite 4.5.3 and node 16.15.2.... I'm working with vuero template, I think that the problem is with the template vuero https://vuero.cssninja.io/
